# Помогите решить задачу C++ заполнить квадратную матрицу

Tags: c++, матрицы

Заполнить квадратную матрицу по следующей схеме:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот есть такой код я сделал его только от 1 до 6 и не могу понять как сделать чтобы при введении любого числа н треугольники были как на примере

```
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        Xray[i][j] = (i == 0 || i == n - 1                                               //верхний и нижний ряд точек
            || i == 3 / 2 <= (n - 1) / 2 && j >= 1 && j <= (n - 2)                           //второй сверху ряд без точек по бокам
            || i == 3 / 2 <= (n - 2) / 2 && j >= 2 && j <= (n - 3)
            || i == (n - 2) && j >= 1 && j <= (n - 2)                                        //предпоследний ряд без точек по бокам
            || i == (n - 3) && j >= 2 && j <= (n - 3)
            || i == (n - 4) && j >= 3 && j <= (n - 4)
            || i == (n - 5) && j >= 4 && j <= (n - 5)
            || i >= (n - 1) / 2 && i <= n / 2 && j >= (n - 1) / 2 && j <= n / 2);            //центральная точка
        cout << Xray[i][j] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    delete[] Xray[i];
delete[] Xray;

return 0;
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Помочь можно, если вы что-то сделали. Показывайте.

Comment: Я не могу собрать треугольники так, чтобы они выдавались под число н автоматически.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно постичь закономерности, и в двойном цикле использовать, например, такое выражение

```
X[i][j] = (abs(2*i-n+1) >= abs(2*j-n+1))? 1: 0
```

Comment: @Мартин Помогло?